# How to get the process name and process state (running or stop) using telegraf procstat plugin

Tags: linux, bash, telegraf, telegraf-inputs-plugin, telegraf-plugins

I am trying to **monitor the system services state (running or stop) using telegraf**. I am pushing all the data into the `influxdb` and trying to visualize it in `grafana`.

My end goal is that i need to visualize the `processname and processstate` from influxdb to grafana.
I used procstat plugin in telegraf to achieve service monitoring.
My telegraf conf file

```
[[inputs.procstat]]
  pattern = ".*"
```

It is by default pushing every process...How can i push the process name and process state from telegraf to influxdb

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for solution on the exact same issue, does any one know how this can be done using telegraf